# Equivalence for artinian and noetherian vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

I'm trying to prove the next proposition:

> For a vector space $V$ over a filed $F$, the next are equivalent:
>
> a) $V$ has a finite dimension
>
> b) $V$ is a finitely generated module
>
> c) $V$ is a Noetherian module
>
> d) $V$ is finitely cogenerated module
>
> e) $V$ is a Artinian module

But I'm stuck when it's about to deal with a finitely cogenerated, whose definition is:

> A $R$-Module $M$ is finitely cogenerated iff for every  family of submodules of $M$, $\hspace{2mm} \{N_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ such that $\cap_{i\in I}N_{i}=\{0\}$ exist $ I_{0}\subseteq I$ finite such thath $\cap_{i\in I_{0}}N_{i}=\cap_{i\in I}N_{i}$

I can prove that a) $\implies$ b) $\implies$ c), and c) $\implies$ b) $\implies$ a) $\implies$ e) but I don't see how to conect c) and d).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For the implication c) $\Rightarrow$ d) you can use the fact that  in a noetherian module every submodules are finitley generated. This might help in finding such finite set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that proving $e)\Rightarrow d)$ would be much easier than connecting $c)$ and $d)$.

Suppose $V$ is not finitely cogenerated. Then there exists a collections $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}$ of submodules of $M$ such that $\cap_i N_i=\{0\}$ but no finite intersection yields $\{0\}$. Suppose $L_0,\ldots,L_{n-1}$ have been defined. Then $\cap_{j=0}^{n-1}L_i\neq\{0\}$, so there exists $L_n\in\{N_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that $\cap_{j=0}^{n-1}L_i\nsubseteq L_n$ and hence $\cap_{j=0}^n L_i\subsetneq\cap_{j=0}^{n-1}L_i$. Then this process defines an infinite descending sequence of submodules $L_0\supsetneq L_0\cap L_1\supsetneq L_0\cap L_1\cap L_2\supsetneq\cdots$ so that $V$ is not Artinian. Hence $e)\Rightarrow d)$ (to be explicit, we used the axiom of dependent choice to guarantee the existence of this sequence).

On the other hand, suppose $V$ is not finite dimensional. Then there is a basis $B$ for $V$ which is not finite. Then $\{\text{span}(B\setminus\{b\})\}_{b\in B}$ is a collection of submodules of $V$ (all with codimension $1$) such that any finite intersection is nontrivial, but whose total intersection is the trivial submodule. Thus, $V$ is not finitely cogenerated, and hence $d)\Rightarrow a)$.

Now, using the directions you have already proven, this shows that all five conditions are equivalent.

Comment: Hello. I would be thankful If you could help to prove d)=>e)

Comment: @ラミタ I already proved $d)\Rightarrow a)$. Do you need help showing $a)\Rightarrow e)$?

Comment: not exactly, I have as an exercise, to show d =>e  directly.

Comment: @ラミタ Then follow my proof of $d)\Rightarrow a)$ and then proof $a)\Rightarrow e)$. This concludes the proof that $d)\Rightarrow e)$.